# Where clause with null condition and != in mysql doesn't return as expected - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a column in a table in our database where we can have either 1, 0 or null. `is_deactivated` that defines the activation status.
I am getting all active rows using a condition on `is_deactivated`.

Why does

```
select * from tableName df (joins on a few table) where  (a few conditions) and (df.is_deactivated IS NULL OR df.is_deactivated = 0)
```

return result and

```
select * from tableName df (joins on a few table) where  (a few conditions) and df.is_deactivated !=1
```

return nothing?

Technically != 1 should return null and 0 ones. I understand it's because of null which is causing this but I wanted to understand the reason/design decision.

Comment: I closed it myself, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your observations would be correct if the `is_deactivated` column happened to only have `NULL` values.  In that case, the first query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tableName df WHERE (df.is_deactivated IS NULL OR df.is_deactivated = 0)
```

would return records as this is clear.  However, the second query would *not* return anything:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tableName df WHERE df.is_deactivated != 1
```

The reason for this is comparing the `NULL` literal against any other value is "unknown," which in this context would evaluate to *false*.  That is, for the `NULL` records, MySQL would report that it cannot be certain that `is_deactivated` is not equal to 1, for those records.

Comment: Somebody is not happy for your answer on a duplicate, haha, thanks btw. I upvoted.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo The thing is, I answered before it was marked duplicate, otherwise I could not have answered.  Anyway, my answer is tailored directly for your question and so is more relevant.